# Hadoop MapReduce - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WordCount$Map

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've compiled and tried to get the following code to run

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.*;

 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

 public class WordCount {

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
      private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
      private Text word = new Text();

      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
          word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
          output.collect(word, one);
        }
      }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
          sum += values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
      conf.setJobName("wordcount");

      conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

      conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
      conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
      conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

      conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

      JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
 }
```

But when I try to run it with with the command 'yarn jar wc.jar WordCount /user/ubuntu/books/holmes.txt /user/ubuntu/output3'
the error message is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WordCount$Map
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount$Map
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
```

I especially don't know where the 'WordCount$Map' is coming from. What am I missing?

Comment: `WordCount$Map` refers to your `static class Map`... `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*` package is deprecated. Please import from `org.apache.hadoop.mapredude` instead

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that didn't do the trick. While compiling there's a new error message beginning with WordCount.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class MapReduceBase
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:12: error: interface expected here
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

Comment: Update: I found my mistake. I didn't create the jar correctly... But it does work with the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.* package as you suggested. So thanks!